# How do I save primary key of child model/table as foreign key in parent model/table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC working on an ASP.NET MVC project for a sheet music inventory system and have two tables: ScoreList and KeySignature. The KeySignature table has primary key(Id) and KeySignatureName. I have another table I'm working with, ScoreListItems, but I think that one is not relevant to my problem.

I am trying to figure out how to do a couple of things.

1) When I create a new ScoreList record, I want the KeySignature field to be a drop down list that populates the KeySignatureNames in from the KeySignature table.

2) When I save the record I want the ScoreList table to store the KeySignatureId.

As I write this it sounds like it should be really easy, but I have been scratching my head all week and can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

Key Signature model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreswellSolution.Model
{
    public class KeySignature
    {
        public int KeySignatureId { get; set; }
        public string KeySignatureName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

ScoreListModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreswellSolution.Model
{
    public class ScoreList : IObjectWithState
    {
        public ScoreList()
        {
            ScoreListItems = new List<ScoreListItem>();
        }

        public int ScoreListId { get; set; }
        public string ScoreListName { get; set; }
        public string ScoreListComposer { get; set; }
        public int KeySignatureId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ScoreListItem> ScoreListItems  { get; set; }

        public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ScoreListViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CreswellSolution.Model;

namespace CreswellSolution.Web.ViewModels
{
    public class ScoreListViewModel : IObjectWithState
    {
        public ScoreListViewModel()
        {
            ScoreListItems = new List<ScoreListItemViewModel>();
            ScoreListItemsToDelete = new List<int>();
        }

        public int ScoreListId { get; set; }
        public string ScoreListName { get; set; }
        public string ScoreListComposer { get; set; }
        public int KeySignatureId { get; set; }

        public List<ScoreListItemViewModel> ScoreListItems { get; set; }

        public List<int> ScoreListItemsToDelete { get; set; }

        public string MessageToClient { get; set; }

        public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Helpers view model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CreswellSolution.Model;

namespace CreswellSolution.Web.ViewModels
{
    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static ScoreListViewModel CreateScoreListViewModelFromScoreList(ScoreList scoreList)
        {
            ScoreListViewModel scoreListViewModel = new ScoreListViewModel();
            scoreListViewModel.ScoreListId = scoreList.ScoreListId;
            scoreListViewModel.ScoreListName = scoreList.ScoreListName;
            scoreListViewModel.ScoreListComposer = scoreList.ScoreListComposer;
            scoreListViewModel.KeySignatureId = scoreList.KeySignatureId;
            scoreListViewModel.ObjectState = ObjectState.Unchanged;

            foreach (ScoreListItem scoreListItem in scoreList.ScoreListItems)
            {
                ScoreListItemViewModel scoreListItemViewModel = new ScoreListItemViewModel();
                scoreListItemViewModel.ScoreListItemId = scoreListItem.ScoreListItemId;
                scoreListItemViewModel.PartName = scoreListItem.PartName;
                scoreListItemViewModel.TotalParts = scoreListItem.TotalParts;
                scoreListItemViewModel.PartsCheckedOut = scoreListItem.PartsCheckedOut;

                scoreListItemViewModel.ObjectState = ObjectState.Unchanged;

                scoreListItemViewModel.ScoreListId = scoreList.ScoreListId;

                scoreListViewModel.ScoreListItems.Add(scoreListItemViewModel);
            }

            return scoreListViewModel;
        }


        public static ScoreList CreateScoreListFromScoreListViewModel(ScoreListViewModel scoreListViewModel)
        {
            ScoreList scoreList = new ScoreList();
            scoreList.ScoreListId = scoreListViewModel.ScoreListId;
            scoreList.ScoreListName = scoreListViewModel.ScoreListName;
            scoreList.ScoreListComposer = scoreListViewModel.ScoreListComposer;
            scoreList.KeySignatureId = scoreListViewModel.KeySignatureId;
            scoreList.ObjectState = scoreListViewModel.ObjectState;

            int temporaryScoreListItemId = -1; 

            foreach (ScoreListItemViewModel scoreListItemViewModel in scoreListViewModel.ScoreListItems)
            {
                ScoreListItem scoreListItem = new ScoreListItem();
                scoreListItem.PartName = scoreListItemViewModel.PartName;
                scoreListItem.TotalParts = scoreListItemViewModel.TotalParts;
                scoreListItem.PartsCheckedOut = scoreListItemViewModel.PartsCheckedOut;

                scoreListItem.ObjectState = scoreListItemViewModel.ObjectState;

                if (scoreListItemViewModel.ObjectState != ObjectState.Added)
                    scoreListItem.ScoreListItemId = scoreListItemViewModel.ScoreListItemId;
                else
                {
                    scoreListItem.ScoreListItemId = temporaryScoreListItemId;
                    temporaryScoreListItemId--;
                }

                scoreListItem.ScoreListId = scoreListViewModel.ScoreListId;

                scoreList.ScoreListItems.Add(scoreListItem);
            }

            return scoreList;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure your entities are modeled correctly. They should resemble something like:

```
public class ScoreList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [ForeignKey("KeySignature")]
    public int KeySignatureId { get; set; }
    public virtual KeySignature KeySignature { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your action, you just need to get an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` with the available `KeySignature` options:

```
var keySignatureOptions = db.KeySignatures.Select(m => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = m.Id.ToString(),
    Text = m.Name
});
```

You can either store this in `ViewBag` or, preferably, utilize a view model and set it on that.

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.KeySignatureId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.KeySignatureOptions)
```

Or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.KeySignatureId, Model.KeySignatureOptions)
```

Depending on which direction your went.

That's it. The selected value will post back to the foreign key property, so you just save as normal and you're done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! I'll give that a try when I get a chance in a few hours.

Comment: I updated my question with some of the code I already have. I am using ViewModels--I have a Helpers class and a ScoreListViewModel class. How do I go about storing the keySignatureOptions variable you mentioned above?